# Can I not receive any input during a state transition? Is that possible?

Tags: state-machine

I know that in FSM, state transition occurs when input changes. But is it possible to receive input when state is changing from one to another?

Answer (score 0):

State changes are considered atomic, so (effectively) nothing happens during the transition.